# Latest AG Grid Update (26.2.0) Broke My Script

Tags: ag-grid

I'm unsure of how to go about modifying my script to work with the new version of AG Grid.  The new version causes no grid to be drawn.  I've reverted to 26.1.0 for now and set up a test page for 26.2.0.  I really don't want to take the tedious approach of going through it line by line.

I'm using ag-grid-community.min.noStyle.js.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it.  For some reason unknown, the latest update will no longer tolerate my use of the delete command to remove array elements before applying the array to the grid with setRowData.  I've changed my coding to use .splice instead.